# How big would my airship have to be to fit a modern VLS system

Tags: armors, airships, vehicles

For my factions anti-occult paramilitary force, I decided to give them large, armoured airships for their main form of transport and attack, which do not use gas bags for lift, but rather a magical lifting crystal (the properties of which will be the subject of future questions).

To aid this force in their duties of flushing out cults and demons, I decided that their main vehicle would be heavily armed as well. In addition to autocannons and machine guns, I decided to try to put a Vertical Launch System (VLS) on them, similar to ones used by modern navies to store missiles.

The missiles in question wil mostly be used for ground attack, like a smaller version of the tomahawk. There would be about 12 missiles per vessel, which would also have other systems, which would add up to around 3 quarters of the rest of the airship.

**TLDR; How big would an airship have to be to carry 12 medium to large guided missiles on it**

Comment: Why would an airship need a VLS? The whole point of VLS is to enable surface based vessels to launch large numbers of missiles in a short period of time high enough into the air so that when their engines ignite/activate they don't damage the ship or vehicle that launched them. Conventional aircraft don't use or need VLS, they simply 'drop' ordinance from an internal magazine and/or hard-points on their surface and let gravity do the 'initial 'launch' process for them. An airship could do the same thing, even if the rockets etc were being fired at targets higher in the atmosphere or beyond.

Comment: Since you are using a magic lifting crystal instead of gas buoyancy or rotors or vectored thrust or other physics-based method, your vessel can be effectively any size, shape, and capability that you want it to be. You can use a swarm of microcrystal bots to float above the enemy capital, locate and decapitate the enemy leadership, and end the war on the first day.

Comment: How big is it supposed to be based only on the missiles? You said it's armored, it must have motors, and fuel... Despite the respondent's enthusiasm so far to try and answer the question, you've given us nothing to work with. What's the crew complement? what's the armor made out of? Is it armored more heavily on the bottom than the top? What's the size of the engines? What range does it have? What does it use for fuel? How fuel efficient is the engine? Does the crew need provisions? Honestly, smaller-than-tomahawk-missiles are the least of your worries when it comes to the size of the airship.

Answer (score 7):

**Mount a VLS? Very big.**

Naval VLS are designed to either cold-launch the cruise missile or to cope with the engine exhaust. The missile goes straight up before it turns in the right direction. In the case of submarines it may have to reach the surface first. The launch is relatively stressful for the vehicle, so there has to be structural reinforcement. All that adds weight.

An [eight-cell VLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_41_Vertical_Launching_System#Mark_41_(Mk_41)) is about 15 tonnes empty. The cruise missiles are about 10 tonnes. Compare that with the useful lift of the [USS Akron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Akron#Specifications_(as_built)), and it *might* be possible to fit a dozen cruise missiles in an airship that size.

**Why mount a VLS?**

If you launch from an airship, it would be much easier to **drop** the cruise missile, let it unfold the wings and start the engine. Perhaps with a booster, perhaps not. Either way, you save a lot of weight with, say, a rotary launcher in a bomb bay, or individual pylons.

Comment: To be fair, dropping a cruise missile is still a VLS. Maybe that was what he/she was after? Because it doesn't make much sense to fire a rocket even higher, unless it's for long distance.

Answer (score 2):

A tomahawk missile weighs in at 1.6 tonne. You request 12 for a total weight of ... 19.2 tonne. Lets call it 20 tonne.
A tomahawk missile is 0.5m by 6.25m. So a naieve 3x4 'cluster' of them would be a cube of 1.5x2x6.25m.
If this is 1/4 of your ship, then the total airship would weigh 80 tonne and be smaller than two 40ft shipping containers next to each other (Unfortunately the max weight capacity of two 40ft containers works out to only 60 tonne, so you'll have to build your own airframe....).

Let's round it all up to 100 tonne. I know you state magic, but ... this is a fairly large traditional airship. Rule of thumb: 1kg/m3 -for helium. This results in 100,000 cubic meters, or a vehicle 100mx50mx20m. Airships of this size/payload capacity do exist.

Because this is an airship, launching a ground-attack-missile is easy: you drop them, and when they have fallen a short distance, the engine ignites. This means you can reduce the infrastructure somehwat. eg: you still need target-radar, but you don't need anti-fratricide covers or rocket-engine-proof-silos. You are effectively building/using some sort of air-launched rocket-bomb.

Comment: The OP states that magic is used instead of a gasbag, which is just as well. Conservation of static heaviness would bite _hard_ after launching a couple of missiles